# Updating shell functions and aliases through environment variables

Tags: shell-script, zsh, environment-variables

Say we define the following shell function and alias in `.zshenv`:

```
export VARIABLE_A='original'

function my_function()
{
    print $VARIABLE_A
}

export VARIABLE_B='original'

alias my_alias="print $VARIABLE_B"
```

Now, say that we start a new interactive shell, and we do the following:

```
$ my_function
$ export VARIABLE_A='new'
$ my_function


$ my_alias
$ export VARIABLE_B='new'
$ my_alias
```

The commands above print:

```
original
new
original
original
```

It looks like the function is updated, but the alias isn't. Is this behavior expected? And if so, why?

Comment: I am not familiar with zsh but instead of `export $FROM=/new/path`, did you try it with just `FROM=/new/path` ?

Comment: @MelBurslan that was just a temporary typo (I actually corrected it 7 minutes before your comment (?)). I am using `FROM=/new/path`

Comment: What `whence -f do_something` outputs?

Comment: I did somethng similar in `bash`. My payload is just `echo ${variable}` instead of your `rsync` and it worked as expected for me. caching (for the lack of a better analogy) might be a zsh *feature*

Comment: Run `set -x` in zsh, set FROM and call `do_something`. Add the output to your answer

Comment: Thanks @skwllsp I have updated the original post, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: On a side note: you do not actually need to export parameters in order to access them anywhere in the current shell context, including functions. You only need `export some_parameter` if you actually want `some_parameter` in the environment of subsequent processes started from this shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the behavior is expected. The reason being simply that you used double quotes (`"…"`) when defining the alias, allowing for parameter substitution. This led to `$VARIABLE_B` being substituted at the time of the definition of the alias instead of its execution.

Essentially, when writing

```sh
VARIABLE_B="original"
alias my_alias="print $VARIABLE_B"
```

`zsh` will replace `$VARIABLE_B` before running the `alias` command like so:

```sh
alias my_alias="print original"
```

Therefore the alias `my_alias` will always be replaced with `print original` before execution.

If you want to substitute a parameter at execution time you have to quote it, either with single quotes (`'…'`) or by quoting `$` with a `\`:

```sh
alias my_alias='print $VARIABLE_B'
alias my_alias="print \$VARIABLE_B"
```

This will set the alias so, that the variable name remains part of the command and the alias `my_alias` is actually replaced with `print $VARIABLE_B` before execution.

---

In contrast parameters inside a function definition do not need to be quoted explicitly, they are always only substituted at runtime.

So when writing

```sh
my_function () {
{
    print $VARIABLE_A
}
```

this is exactly what will be stored. When running `my_function` `$VARIABLE_A` 
will be substituted with the value it has at that time.

Answer (score 0):

> Say we define the following shell function and alias in .zshenv:

Aliases are evaluated on execution of a script. So $VARIABLE_B is evaluated and replaced with its value at the moment when your .zshenv is processed. Whatever value you will assign to VARIABLE_B later is not going to affect the alias.

On the contrary functions do not evaluate enviroment variables when they are processed. Enviroment variables in function are evaluted when a function is called.